# Trigger/invoke a Chrome extension from a web page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

For the project I'm currently working on, I need to know if it is possible to invoke a Chrome extension.

I.e., clicking on a button (or a link) on my page would call the "Read It" extension, something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject your `content-script` to every page (register it in [extension manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest)) and alter the page html to add your `button` or `a` with your custom id.

The [execution environment example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) explains it pretty good how you will trigger an event from the page to your content script. After you manage the trigger you can do anything you want as the extension logic.

Also keep in mind that this will require your extension's `content-script` to be injected to every page the user visits. It is not possible to actually trigger the execution of your `content-script` from the page if thats what you were asking.

Comment: Can you explain it further? I also have to invoke an extension via programming. Extension loads up by hitting it's icon button on bottom right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You could write a so-called [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to alter the page and hook event handlers to the links or buttons.

Answer (score 1):

create a manifest with background.js and content.js  . 
Use

`chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {}, function() { ... });`

in background to send messages to content script which is injected into every webpage that is opened when extension is installed and enabled . 
On the content.js script use

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(req, sender, callback) {  
    // here use condition to find out when this extension's popup.html should be opened
    // and call the callback function which was passed in the argument list initially
    callback("something");
});
```

Here the callback function defines in background.js and passed to content.js is the code for opening a new extension window such as

```
var panel_props = {
            type: 'panel',
            'width': width,
            'height': height,
            'left': left,
            'top': top,
            url: "chrome-extension://" + <extensionid>+ "/index.html"   
          }

          chrome.windows.create(panel_props ,function (newWindow) { 
              vid = newWindow.id;
          });
```

Comment: for description of manifest.json ( if required ) leave a comment . I'll included that as well

Comment: Again, nonsensical answer. This does not relate to the question in any way - but I'll be happy to be proven wrong if you can explain how it does.

Comment: Dear Xan , I welcome your crudeness . The answer is right and to the point in my opinion . The chrome extension gives the power to activate contentjs from a listening background script . Using this as trigger the extension can be directly called from any webpage .  You should read this " https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-make-a-chrome-extension"

Comment: @Xan  A content script is “a JavaScript file that runs in the context of web pages.” This means that a content script can interact with web pages that the browser visits. - picked from above URL

Comment: Yes, but the question was how to activate the extension code _from a webpage code/UI_. Thank you, being in top 5 users on [tag:google-chrome-extension] I know what a content script is.

Comment: Lol really , so do answer how else would you activate code in extesnion without using content and background scripts . I await a quick and perfect reply .

Comment: I'm not claiming that the code in your answer is incorrect. My claim is "it's not answering the question". Take a look at the example the question gives - _"clicking on a button (or a link) **on my page** would call the "Read It" extension"_ (emphasis mine) This is the essence of the question - how does your answer deal with it? How sending a message from the background script is related to this situation?

Comment: Fine let me tell you that according to me chrome.windows.create or chrome.tabs.create using the extension id is the way to do it , which I have clearly mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72217/discussion-between-xan-and-altanai).

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a "fake" ajax call in your web page code.
2. Intercept it in your extension (see https://medium.com/@gilfink/adding-web-interception-abilities-to-your-chrome-extension-fb42366df425)
3. In the intercept, cancel the "fake" call and implement your desired behaviour.