# Run browser toolbar button using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have added a chrome extension called "External Application Button".

What it does is we can add external application like sublime.exe, vscode.exe etc to our browser toolbar and on click , it opens the exe.

So using jquery or javascript is it possible to make that button click happen?

My main goal is to make that application run using jquery or javascript code in a webpage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger/invoke a Chrome extension from a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712810/trigger-invoke-a-chrome-extension-from-a-web-page)

Comment: I don't think it is. I may be wrong, but code *on the page* is generally quite different from the one that defines an extension. Well, unless they both modify the page, that is. The extension is also given (some) access to modifying the browser, page code isn't.

Comment: OP "My main goal is to make that application run using jquery or javascript code **in a webpage**." I'm pretty sure it's exactly the same thing. The javascript engine is sandboxed, meaning it can't affect anything outside the page, *unless* an extension injects some code into the page that allows the javascript engine access to the extension.

Comment: Can u please show me a code sample? Suppose i gave "mybutton" id to the button how can i trigger click for that button? It would be helpful

Comment: And what would i have to do so that my code will work in every browser

Answer (score 1):

1. Both for an extension and a webpage it's impossible to do it on its own, without installing extra software. You are "sandboxed" in what you can do on a computer from your code, and limited to whatever APIs browsers provide.
2. To invoke an application external to the browser, an extension needs to use something called [Native Host](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). This is why installing something extra is required to make that extension work.

   Regular webpages can't use Native Hosts, so that route is closed.
3. Can we do it from webpage code, if we allow installing an extension?

   Yes, an extension that talks to a webpage (through content scripts, or `externally_connectable` mechanism) can allow websites to trigger extension code, that triggers native host code, that does what you want.

   You can't do that with arbitrary third party extensions, so you'll need to write your own.
4. Can you do it anyway, without an extension, if we allow installing an extra component?

   In principle, yes. A typical way to do it is to install a helper program that opens a web server on a local port, e.g. `localhost:12345`. Then any JavaScript context can try connecting to it.

   In practice, there are complications.

   - How do you secure your local server from arbitrary connections? You'd need some pre-shared secret to not allow other sites, or other software on the local machine, to abuse this.
   - Connecting to non-HTTPS domains from HTTPS websites is a problem. Making a certificate for `localhost` that's trusted by the browser is also a problem (that has security implications if circumvented). That complicates installation of the extra component.
5. Another idea: your extra component can register itself as a protocol handler. For example, you can add a `launch-app:` protocol and tell the system that your helper application needs to be invoked. Example: Steam uses this approach to communicate with its client from the browser (e.g. to install / start a game).

   Note that this is one-way communication, but for the "launch a program" use case it's enough.

   Then you can just provide links to that special protocol to do that. Again, this requires installation of an extra component in the target system. You can't do that with just the browser.

So the overall answer is: it's complicated, and needs extra software installation.